# PyCharm Windows: how to modify the shell PATH of the command line?

Tags: pycharm

In the `Settings > Tools > Terminal` menu, you can read [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-tools-terminal.html) that you can change the Shell path and there are example of how to add parameters.

I want to be able to launch the default "`cmd.exe`" with the option that changes the `PATH` like this:

```
cmd.exe /k "set PATH=C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Scripts;%PATH%"
```

However when I add those option I get "`java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY`"

I've tried many things, including enclosing everything with quotes, simple quotes, double quotes...

How to run `cmd.exe` with those options?
(Note: I don't want to change my global `PATH` settings (where I use Python36), I just want to change the path for this specific project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of those (works for me):

```
"cmd.exe" /k ""set PATH=C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Scripts;%PATH%""
```

or

```
cmd.exe "/k set PATH=C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Scripts;%PATH%"
```

And then when you launch the terminal:

```
C:\Users\Olivier\Documents\PyCharmProjects\chat>echo %PATH%
C:\Python35;C:\Python35\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\[..blabla..]
```

Comment: Strange - also sitting on latest pycharm - had same error when posted your example and when updated to this for me error is gone; may be try to restart pycharm

Comment: that's ok, do it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this answer, i've managed to add the PHP cli interpreter path in **PhpStorm** to terminal with the help of **_INTELLIJ_FORCE_PREPEND_PATH** variable

```
cmd.exe "/K set PATH=%_INTELLIJ_FORCE_PREPEND_PATH%%PATH%"
```